# Unchecking all checkbox inserted with an each loop

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I want to know how I could uncheck all checkboxes in this template, I tried using jquery but it messes up with my observer on isChecked :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="conversations">   
{{#each conv in model itemController='singleconv'}}
    <div class="conversation-content-wrapper" {{action "clickConv" conv preventDefault=false}}>
            <div class="history-message-assigned in-progress-closed" style="display:none;"><p><i class="icon-x"></i>Conversation closed</p></div>
            <div class="history-message-assigned in-progress-assignation" style="display:none;"><p><i class="icon-assign"></i>Conversation assigned</p></div>
            <div class="history-message-assigned in-progress-reopen" style="display:none;"><p><i class="icon-re-opened"></i>Conversation re-opened</p></div>          
        <div class="conversation-history">          
            <div class="conversation-time-history">{{{conv.timeAgoElement}}}</div>
            <div class="conversation-details">
                <span class="unread-numbers"></span>
                    {{input type='checkbox' class='chk-conversation' checked=conv.isChecked}}
                     <span class="conversation-name">{{conv.customer.name}}</span>
                     <span class="phone-number">{{conv.customer.cellPhoneNumber}}</span>
                    <p class="conversation-text">{{conv.lastMessage}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>                       
    </div>
{{/each}}     
</script>
```

How can I retrieve all the instances of this model's checkboxes and uncheck them all in a function?

Answer (score 0):

The check box is checked based on each models `isChecked` property.

If you loop through each model and change `isChecked` to `false` it will uncheck all the check boxes.

Comment: Where do I code it? In the array controller?  Can you tell me about the syntax of this loop on the model? Thanks